# Ellipsoid expression effect on characteristic equation

Tags: rotations, solid-geometry, ellipsoids

In "An algebraic condition for the separation of two ellipsoids" ([https://i.cs.hku.hk/~ykchoi/quadrics/Ellipsoid_Separation.pdf](https://i.cs.hku.hk/%7Eykchoi/quadrics/Ellipsoid_Separation.pdf)) , the authors offer conditions for ellipsoid intersection that depend on expressing ellipsoids as

$$
\mathcal{A}: X^{T} A  X, \\
\mathcal{B}: X^{T} B  X,
$$

where $X = (x,y,z,w)^{T}$, $A$ or $B$ is a 4 by 4 matrix, and their "characteristic equation" is defined as
$$
f(\lambda) = \text{det}(A \lambda + B) = 0.
$$
If I want to deal with ellipsoids that are defined more normally, like
$$
\mathcal{C}: (X-X_0)^{T} C  (X-X_0)
$$
with $X = (x,y,z)^{T}$ and now $X_0$ including the center coordinates, so $C$ is 3 by 3, can I still use the same conditions for intersection? I would think the characteristic equation must change (from maximally 4 roots to maximally 3), and I can't use the same conditions. Is there a simple way to convert from the form of $C$ to that of $A$ or $B$?
I want to so I can easily rotate the ellipsoid first (I can't apply a 3 by 3 rotation matrix to an ellipsoid equation that uses a 4 by 4 center matrix).

Comment: I have a way to convert C to A, actually, (it's vey straightforward) so the effect on the characteristic equation isn't important after all.